# Sharing code among views in Django

Tags: django, view

Forgive me if this has been asked repeatedly, but I couldn't find an example of this anywhere.

I'm struggling to understand how to share code among view functions in Django.  For example, I want to check if the user is authenticated in many views.  If they're not, I'd like to log some information about that request (IP address, etc.) then display a canned message about needing authentication.

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably best accomplished by creating a utils.py file, rather than a view.  Views that don't return an HTTPResponse object are not technically valid.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

> "Each view is responsible for doing one of two things: Returning an HttpResponse object containing the content for the requested page, or raising an exception such as Http404." ... "All Django wants is that HttpResponse. Or an exception."

Heroku will throw an error if the view does not return an HttpResponse.

What I usually do in this instance is write a function in a separate file called utils.py and import it and use it from the application files that need it.

```
from utils import check_login

def view1(request):
     check_login(request)  
     pass  
def view2(request):
     check_login(request)  
     pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write those code in a function, then call it in many views.
For example:

```
def check_login():  
     pass  
def view1():
     check_login()  
     pass  
def view2():
     check_login()  
     pass
```

Comment: Oh wow, how dumb of me.  Thanks for the info.  For some reason, I was assuming that those functions could only be called as the endpoint for a URL.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to use decorators just like in django's [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator), however if you need something more complex maybe you want something like [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)